# Infinite sum with primes

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I am trying to prove that the following sum converges for s>1:

$ \sum_{p \text{ prime}} \lvert \frac{1}{p^s-1} \rvert$

Does anyone have ideas about which direction I should go?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for $s>1$ the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{1}{p^s-1}<\frac{2}{p^s}\iff 2<p^s$$

Now, what do you know of $\sum_{n\geq1}\tfrac{1}{n^s}$?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove something stronger:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ converges for $s>1$ (in fact it is the Riemann zeta function at $s$).

To show this we can just note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{m^s}\leq 1+ \int\limits_{1}^n \frac{1}{x^s}dx=\frac{m^{1-s}-1}{1-s}$.

Since $s>1$ the right side converges to $\frac{1}{s-1}$ when $m$ goees to infinity.